# Django poor performance when annotating on multiple related fields

Tags: python, django

I've recently run into a performance problem with one of my Django views.

I use models that resemble these example models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='comments')
```

In my view I need to display how many posts and comments each user has written, and I get the queryset like so:

```
User.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts', distinct=True),
                      comment_count=Count('comments', distinct=True))
```

This works as expected, however recently performance has become really poor with increased number of rows in the database.
I have approximately:

```
Users: 1300
Comments: 4300
Posts: 6200
```

And the query takes approximately 400ms.

If I remove either `post_count` or `comment_count` from the query, execution time drops down to an acceptable 10ms.

I suspect this comes from joining the extra table, which raises the total number of rows to `1300 * 4300 * 6200` instead of eg. `1300 * 4300`.

But how do I circumvent this problem, is the best solution to simply store the number of comments and posts in the database as a field and make application logic take care of updating it when needed?

Answer (score 0):

As you have relations prefetch_related might be help you to increase performance.

```
User.objects.prefetch_related('posts').prefetch_related('comments').annotate('any thing you like for aggregation')
```